# email keyboard is in landscape?

Tags: objective-c, xcode

my app is in landscape mode, when i open the email sheet, that is in portrait-**and its ok**, the keyboard is opened in landscape,so i have portrait email sheet,and landscape keyboard.

How do i fix it , that the keyboard will be in in portrait also ?
WHY when pressing "cancel" , its not going back to the app and nothing happens ?

```
//send email log-------------------------
        NSLog(@"mail");
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] pause];

        picker = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        picker.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        //Fill in the email as you see fit
        NSArray *toRecipients = [NSArray arrayWithObject:@"r@gmail.com"]; 
        [picker setToRecipients:toRecipients];


        NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
        NSString *dataPath = [[paths objectAtIndex:0] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"BetaTest.txt"];
        NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:dataPath];
        [picker addAttachmentData:data mimeType:@"text/txt" fileName:@"BetaTest.txt"];

        NSString *emailBody = @"test :) ";
        [picker setMessageBody:emailBody isHTML:NO];
        [picker setSubject:@"hardware test##"];

        //display the view
        [[[CCDirector sharedDirector] openGLView] addSubview:picker.view];
        [[CCDirector sharedDirector] stopAnimation];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of adding the view of the `MFMailComposeViewController` instance to your currently active view, you'll need to display it as a modal view controller.  Unfortunately, cocos2d (which I assume you are using from the `CCDirector` class you have in your code) isn't built on top of the default UIKit displays.

This means you'll have to find your application's root view controller and call its `presentModalViewController:` method.  There are several ways to do this, for example the method detailed in this blog post (written by someone else, but a decent approach): http://indiedevstories.com/2011/06/25/modal-view-controllers-in-cocos2d/